# Check directory exists in hdfs using shell conditionals

Tags: bash, hadoop, if-statement

I'm creating a prompt script that will validate if the output directory exists in the hdfs directory. This is what I came up with

```
while true; do
    read -p  "What is the table name ?" table_name
    case "$table_name" in
       * ) if (( $(hdfs dfs -test -d /user/hive/bar/foo/$test_table) )) ; 
           then echo "ok"; else echo "not ok"; fi ;;
       esac
done
```

This is not working. I don't get any errors but the output is always "not ok" ever if the condition is true.

Comment: You could use `if hdfs dfs -test -d /user/hive/bar/foo/$test_table ; then` instead of using the `((` operator to check the exit code

Comment: That worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of violations (syntactic/semantic) for your initial edit.

1. The string in the `case` clause `case '$table_name' in` will never expand, because present under the single-quotes.  It will not throw an error because you are trying to match a literal string without any expansion done. You need to double-quote it as `case "$table_name"`
2. Multiple `*)` will never work, the case present 2<sup>nd</sup> will never match as always the first expression matches. Replace it with an actual expression

---

With your update script, the problem is checking success return code of the a command inside the `((` operator which is meant for arithmetic evaluation. You just needed to use

```
if hdfs dfs -test -d /user/hive/bar/foo/$test_table; then
    printf 'table exists\n'
fi
```

The rationale is that there is one way (0) for a command to succeed but many ways (any non-zero integer) for it to fail. Don't confuse `bash`'s use of exit statuses with the standard Boolean interpretation of 0 as false and nonzero as true. The shell if statement checks if its command succeeds.